# Event-Sourcing: How to handle Projections?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, projection, event-sourcing

I have three aggregates, a **Task**, a **User**, and a **User Group**. The aggregates are event-sourced. I also have two projections, a collection of **Tasks** and a collection of **User Groups**. These are built from the events. My users want to filter the **Tasks** based on the **User Groups** they are in. What approach should I take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At some point, there will be the event of assigning a certain task (or a list of tasks) to a certain user group.
The projection of that event then writes some information about that relationship into your read store. Depending on your use case and database technology, this could be a simple property added to each projected task / task list, or you could build pre-filtered lists for each user group.

In Event Sourcing, the event stream represents the source of truth. Thus, the projected data can be tailored much more towards certain representation needs than it is the case with traditional, relational data.

Comment: Thanks!. I should say, each record in the **Tasks** projection already has a key which holds the associated **User Group**. I like the idea of having pre-filtered lists but it could mean I need to update a lot of records when group membership changes. Alternatively, I could find which groups the user is in by querying the **User Groups** projection, then use that to query the **Tasks** projection. However, there is something about this that doesn't feel quite right. Thoughts?

Comment: Both are valid options, depends on your requirements. As you already mentioned, updating pre-filtered collections might be problematic in case there are a lot of writes. Without knowing the details of your system, I would propose you may want to start with the most simple solution to implement, which is the second approach you mentioned. If things get slow, you still can optimize using more sophisticated projections.